# code not printing to the way .format is coded

Tags: python

```
myfile = open('Results.txt')
title = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20}'.format('Player Nickname','Matches Played','Matches Won','Matches Lost','Points')
print(title)
for line in myfile:
    item = line.split(',')
    points = int(item[2]) * 3
    if points != 0:
        result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20}'.format(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3],points)
        print(result)
```

Hi there just need a little help with those who knows how to use .format properly, for some reason when the answers are printed. I would expect this.

```
Player Nickname      Matches Played       Matches Won          Matches Lost         Points 
Leeroy               19                   7                    12                   21
```

But the displayed output I get is this

```
  Player Nickname      Matches Played       Matches Won          Matches Lost         Points              
  Leeroy               19                   7                    12
                                   21
```

21 is being displayed in the wrong place. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Looks like `item[3]` contains new line character. Could you check data in file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is simply remove white spaces using strip(),

```
result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20}'.format(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3],str(points).strip())
```

If new line is there you can omit it with,

```
str(points).replace('\n','')
```

Comment: partially correct the new line was on item[3] not points but thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default integers are aligned to right and strings to left:

```
>>> '{:20}'.format(100)
'                 100'
>>> '{:20}'.format('100')
'100                 '
```

You can either explicitly specify left alignment or convert `int` to string before passing it to `format`:

```
result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:<20}'.format(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], points)
result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20}'.format(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], str(points))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help it still prints a similar output with only the number a little more closer

Comment: @MineFlamerKaiBin Could be newline character as comments suggested,  add `print(item)` to see what are the contents.